# What is wrong with this proof of Krull Intersection Theorem?

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a module over a ring $R$ and $I$ an ideal. $I^\infty M= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty I^kM$. Then $I \cdot I^\infty M=\bigcap_{k=2}^\infty I^k M.$ Clearly we have $\bigcap_{k=2}^\infty I^k M \supseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty I^k M$. But $IM \supseteq I^2M$, so $\bigcap_{k=2}^\infty I^{k}M = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty I^k M$, and therefore
$I \cdot I^\infty M = I^\infty M$.

This proof avoids Artin-Reese, which seems to be frequently used to prove the Krull intersection theorem. I'm not sure why you would avoid using this proof, but the textbooks seem to.

Comment: A simple proof that avoids Artin-Reese was discovered in 2004 by Hervé Perdu. There's a good presentation of the proof in http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/ca.html

Comment: The symbol $\cap$ is used in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n$ and $\bigcap$ is used in things like $\bigcap_{k=2}^\infty A_k$ and $\displaystyle \bigcap_{k=2}^\infty A_k.$ I edited this question accordingly.

Comment: the reasoning you are using is of the kind $f(\cap_n A_n)= \cap_n f(A_n)$ which is false in general, only the inclusion $\subset$ works in general.

Answer (score 4):

Products don't necessarily commute with intersections.

So you can't claim $I \cdot I^\infty M=\bigcap_{k=2}^\infty I^k M$.

Note that in your proof attempt, you didn't specify any conditions on the ring $R$ or on the module $M$ (e.g., $R$ is noetherian, $M$ is finitely generated), and without at least *some* additional conditions, there are known counterexamples to the claim of the Krull Intersection Theorem.

For example, see the following thread . . .

$\qquad$https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71699

With regard to the issue of whether products commute with intersections . . .

In general, if

- $R$ is a ring.$\\[4pt]$

  $I$ is an ideal of $R$.$\\[4pt]$

  $M$ is an $R$-module.$\\[4pt]$

  $S$ is a collection of sub-modules of $M$.

then we get
$$
I
\left(
\bigcap_{M\in S}M
\right)
\subseteq
\bigcap_{M\in S}IM 
$$
but the reverse inclusion need not hold.

In fact, products don't necessarily commute even with *finite* intersections.

As an example, let

- $R=\mathbb{Z}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $I=(2)$.$\\[4pt]$

  $G$ be the finite abelian group $Z_4\times Z_6$.$\\[4pt]$

  $A$ be the $4$-element cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $(1,0)$.$\\[4pt]$

  $B$ be the $4$-element cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $(1,3)$.

Then

- $A\cap B$ is the $2$-element cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $(2,0)$, hence $I(A \cap B)=0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $IA$ and $IB$ are both equal to the cyclic subgroup generated by $(2,0)$, hence
  $IA\cap IB \ne 0$.

Thus, for this example, $I(A \cap B)$ is a proper subset of $IA \cap IB$.

Comment: Do you have a simple example of the noncommutation? It seemed very innocuous to me.

Comment: @Watson Ladd: Innocuous is not a proof. Can you _prove_ commutation, even for the case of finite intersections? As for counterexamples, any counterexample to the Krull Intersection Theorem (with reduced hypotheses), as for example, those given in the referenced thread, will yield a counterexample to commutation.

Comment: "it seemed innocuous" makes for a great tombstone inscription.

Comment: @Watson Ladd: I edited in a simple example to show that products need not commute with intersections.

Comment: @quasi My argument was that cap I^{k}M is elements of the form I^{k}m for all $k$, so we can just shift down the representation one.

Comment: @Watson Ladd: Your argument fails at the step where you bring $I$ inside the intersection. You are effectively assuming that products commute with intersections, which is not true in general. The fact that you made no use of the noetherian condition on $R$, or the finitely generated condition on $M$, should have raised warning flags  with regard to the validity of your proof attempt.